# Using the energy consumption profiler in Visual Studio 2015 Community

Tags: visual-studio

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Community version, and I tried to use the energy consumption tool.

I used

```
Debug -> Profiler -> Start Diagnostic Tools Without Debugging...
```

However, I found that the "Energy Consumption" option is not available. 
(The option was shown but was shown as "not available.")

Is the energy consumption profiler not available for the free version I am using? 
Or is there any setting I missed...

Comment: The energy profiler is only available for Windows Store apps, is that what you are creating?

Comment: No. I am not creating a Windows apps... Is there any alternative for profiling the energy consumption?